# Trying to call Oracle MAIL_PKG with arrays and getting PLS-00201: identifier 'MAIL_PKG.ARRAY' must be declared

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to create a simple PL/SQL program which will:

a) get a current number of active session on db from v$session

b) compare the result to average active session baseline (i collect the data on table on user1 schema by simple job running every 5 minutes)

If a > b then an email should be send to a defined recipents - I have a whole mailing package on oracle on schema1. But whenever I try to run the following code:

```
 declare
  SESS_COUNT NUMBER;
  SESS_AVG NUMBER;
  SUB           VARCHAR2(500);
  BODY          VARCHAR2(500);
  INSTANCE_NAME VARCHAR(200);
  HOST_NAME     VARCHAR(500);

BEGIN
 SELECT COUNT(*)
 INTO SESS_COUNT
 FROM v$session
WHERE status='ACTIVE';

SELECT ROUND(AVG(SESS_COUNT)) 
INTO SESS_AVG 
FROM user1.SESS_ACTIVE;

IF SESS_COUNT > SESS_AVG 

  THEN
   SELECT INSTANCE_NAME INTO INSTANCE_NAME FROM V$INSTANCE;
    SELECT HOST_NAME INTO HOST_NAME FROM V$INSTANCE;
    SUB  := INSTANCE_NAME || '@' || HOST_NAME ||' - MAIL_TOPIC';
    BODY := 'MAIL_BODY:'|| SESS_COUNT;
    SCHEMA1.MAIL_PKG.SEND_MAIL(INSTANCE_NAME || '_'|| HOST_NAME||'@domain1', MAIL_PKG.ARRAY('user.123@net.ca'), SUB, BODY);
  END IF;
END;
```

I get error:

```
ORA-06550: line 26, column 79:
PLS-00201: identifier 'MAIL_PKG.ARRAY' must be declared
```

I will be grateful for any tips - I tried to declare MAIL_PKG.ARRAYS in various ways, but nothing works.

Comment: MAIL_PKG.ARRAY must be a procedure,function or type in your mail_pkg package whose definition would be missing in specification. Check out

Comment: If you are running the PL/SQL in different schema, Try appending this package's schema name, `SCHEMA1.MAIL_PKG.ARRAY ` . If it exists.

Comment: Can you mention the specification of the package `MAIL_PKG.SEND_MAIL` that will help more.